# Using a function from a js file in an ejs file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

So I have a function (see below) which I have written in a file called **modifier.js** that I have exported to my **app.js** file with all my routes.

```
function displayModCost(){
    var cost = "THIS IS A TEST";
    return cost;
}

module.exports = {displayModCost}
```

I've required the **modifer.js** file in my **app.js** file and added the variable to the GET route (along with my database) for the page I am trying to render.

```
var myFunctionsMod = require("./public/javascript/modifier");

app.get("/modifiers", function(req,res){
    Modifier.find({}, function(err,modifiers){
        if(err){
            console.log("ERROR ON THE INDEX ROUTE OF THE MODIFIERS PAGE")
        } else{
            res.render("modifierIndex",{modifiers:modifiers, func:myFunctionsMod});
        }
    });
});
```

I then used the following code in my ejs file:

```
<div class="modCost"><p><%func.displayModCost()%></p></div>
```

The problem I am having is that when I go to the webpage nothing is displaying in the div with the displayModCost function ([it's empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE7RM.png)).

I'm getting no error messages so I'm wondering what I am doing wrong (or if there is a better way to get the function to work). I plan to add more functions to the file in the future so I don't want to write the function in my ejs file.

Comment: think should be `module.exports = displayModCost` and should be `<%=`

Comment: Thanks Lawrence. Adding the = sign to the <%= got the function to work. I also tried it without the {} just to see if it still works and it gives me the error message func.displayModCost is not a function (so I guess the {} are necessary).